# How to run selenium standalone server with Edge webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to run Selenium tests against Edge, in the same way I successfully run with Chrome or Internet Explorer 11 but it fails.

What I do is starting the standalone selenium and it works fine:

```
java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\tmp\msedgedriver.exe -jar C:\tmp\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4445
```

But when I run the Selenium tests, it fails with the error below:

I've tried to add "-DbrowserName=edge" but it does not make any difference.

Is there something I've missed?

> Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time:
>   '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z' System info: host: 'MSEDGEWIN10', ip:
>   '10.0.2.15', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:89)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:171)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.(DefaultSession.java:88)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:76)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:72)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:63)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:37)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:112)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:191)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.lambda$handleRequest$0(DriverServlet.java:261)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 08:13:43.301 WARN - Exception: The best matching driver provider class
>   org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance
>   for Capabilities {browserName: edge}

Comment: EdgeDriver is now a Windows Feature on Demand.  So you always link to the local version that's in SYSWOW64:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Comment: This is what I've done, msedgedriver.exe is downloaded from this URL.

Comment: Check your Edge version... From the page: "Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) versions 18 and 19 is a Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver. To get started you will have to enable Developer Mode:
Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developer and then select “Developer mode”."

Comment: Interesting...I would like to run Microsoft Edge (Chromium) and not Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) known as "on demand" so as far as I understood, I only need to select the appropriate microsoft edge chromium driver and use it, right ?

Comment: I see, I'm using Microsoft Edge that comes preinstalled with Windows 10 so it's Edge44.17763.1.0  which requires Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763 so I can not use Chromium WebDriver unless I use Edge based on Chromium which is not yet available (at least in Beta). So you're right, I need to install Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML).

Comment: @user3611522, your last 2 comments are confusing. Web driver for Edge Chromium is available. You can download it from this link. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ Current latest version is 78.0.249.0.  I can see that you are using JAVA but I am available with C# example. you can try to refer it as an reference. https://textuploader.com/11psv Try to correct us if we misunderstood anything.

Comment: Yes web driver for Edge chromium is available, my concern is that I did not see  any Edge Chromium browser delivered for Windows 10 except iprovided as dev version.

Comment: Currently the MS Edge (Chromium) browser is in the development stage and beta version is available for download. it is expected that browser will get officially launched soon. If you are still getting the error in your code than please try to post your sample code which can produce the issue. We will try to make a tests with it to check for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: I suppose that you're interesting in any error I may face with Ms Edge (Chromium) right ? So far, I finally stick on Edge HTML and wait for Final Edge (Chromium) version.

Comment: Thanks for updating the status of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the java code I wrote to use Feature on Demand EdgeDriver.  This has not been tested, so if you use it, let me know if it works:

```
      String windir = System.getenv("windir");
                boolean is64bit = false;

      is64bit = (System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null);
      String edgeDriverPath = windir + "\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
        if (!is64bit)
        {
        edgeDriverPath = windir + "\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
        }

       System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", edgeDriverPath); 
       EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();

       //edgeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(stringPageLoadConstant);
         try {
             driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
             }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
            System.out.println ("Problem launching EdgeDriver: " + ex.toString());      
            }
```

Comment: No, it does not work.
There is no MicrosoftWebDriver.exe in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Nor is there anything that called WebDriver, or EdgeDriver. 
Lots of DLLs, though.

Comment: You would need to install the Feature on Demand first... "DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver": https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/  It sounds like for v19 and above you just need to turn on Developer mode and it installs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I did run the DISM.exe command.  But I have no idea if it really worked.  I'm running Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363. So I'm not on v19.  Where do they hide the executable?

Comment: I've been told you don't even need to set the path... (probably sets in PATHS var), but it should be in System32 or SYSWOW64 depending on your OS bit-ness.

Comment: I had set it up for that, but it didn't work. OTOH, today I had to reboot twice, and now it works!  
String windir = System.getenv("windir");
String edgeDriverPath = windir + "\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", edgeDriverPath); 
Common.driver = new EdgeDriver();